# How can I get the first element's text using Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to get the text for `Last sold date` from this HTML:

```
<td class="browse-cell-date">

    <span title="Last sold date">
        May 2002 
    </span>

    <button class="btn btn-previous-sales js-btn-previous-sales">
        Previous sales (1) <i class="icon icon-down-open-1"/>
    </button>

    <div class="previous-sales-panel is-hidden">
        <span style="display: block;">
            Aug 1997
            <span class="fright">£60,000</span>
        </span>
    </div>

</td>
```

I tried:

```
    date = val.search(".//td[@class='browse-cell-date']").children[1]
```

It gave me the span I wanted but after adding `.text` to it, did not returned anything.

Comment: have you tried `.val()`?

Comment: @davidhu2000, just used `val` and got an err `NoMethodError (undefined method `val' for nil:NilClass):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start with:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
    <td class="browse-cell-date">

        <span title="Last sold date">
            May 2002 
        </span>

        <button class="btn btn-previous-sales js-btn-previous-sales">
            Previous sales (1) <i class="icon icon-down-open-1"/>
        </button>

        <div class="previous-sales-panel is-hidden">
            <span style="display: block;">
                Aug 1997
                <span class="fright">£60,000</span>
            </span>
        </div>

    </td>
EOT

sold_date = doc.at('span[title="Last sold date"]') # => #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3ffc7e84c35c name="span" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3ffc7e84c2f8 name="title" value="Last sold date">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ffc7e82bc10 "\n            May 2002 \n        ">]>
sold_date.text # => "\n            May 2002 \n        "
sold_date.text.strip # => "May 2002"
```

So

```
doc.at('span[title="Last sold date"]').text.strip # => "May 2002"
```

will do it.

`at` is like `search('some selector').first` so use it for convenience. Both `at` and `search` are smart enough to figure out whether the selector is CSS or XPath most of the time so I use those. If Nokogiri is fooled I'll revert to using one of the `*_css` or `*_xpath` variants.

Alternately you could use:

```
doc.at('td.browse-cell-date span').text.strip # => "May 2002"
doc.at('td.browse-cell-date > span').text.strip # => "May 2002"
```

Note: Using `text` with any of the `search`, `xpath` or `css` methods isn't a good idea. Those methods return a NodeSet, which doesn't do what you expect when you use its `text` method. Consider these examples:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
    <body>
        <p>foo</p>
        <p>bar</p>
    </body>
</html>
EOT

doc.search('p').class # => Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet
doc.search('p').text # => "foobar"
```

We regularly see questions where people have done this and then need to figure out how to split the concatenated text into something useful, which usually is very difficult.

99.99% of the time, you want to use the following `map(&:text)` to extract the text from a NodeSet:

```
doc.search('p').map(&:text) # => ["foo", "bar"]
```

But, in your use, simply use `at`, which returns a Node and then `text` will do what you expect.

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```
page.search(".//td").children[1].attr("title")
```

Comment: The OP doesn't want the contents of the `title` parameter, instead what's in the first `<span>`.